# How can I get isc-dhcp-server/dhcpd to listen on one interface only?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhcpd

I would like my `isc-dhcp-server` instance to listen on my LAN interface only because I'm investigating an issue with my "WiFi router" and configured `INTERFACES='p18p1'` in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` where `p18p1` is my LAN interface. However, after restart with `sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service` if see

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           23088/dhcpd
```

in the output of `sudo netstat -tupln | grep 67` which leads me to believe that the `interfaces` configuration value is ignored. Specifying `interfaces p18p1;` in `/etc/dhcpd/dhcpd.conf` causes the `systemd` unit to fail to start - it seems to enforce specification of interfaces in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Whats the output of `systemctl cat isc-dhcp-server.service`?  Also if you do `sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart`, does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try seting the `INTERFACE` variable in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` to the desired interface. For example:

```
INTERFACES="eth2"
```

Comment: didn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the following to top of the `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file? The syntax might be important:

```
INTERFACES="p18p1";
```

This worked for me in Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS while having multiple active interfaces with different subnets. Assuming no other similar configs exist at the same time anywere else.